# Multiple Call Forwarding, forward recorded call to mail, Voice mail trigger

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I'm new to this twilio and I looking for below solutions

**1) Multiple Call Forwarding**

- I want to forward call one after another (Consider 3 numbers)
- If A not picked up, then it should forward call to B and if B not yet picking then Forward to C.
- If any one picked up the call, then no need to forward calls to another numbers
- I'm planning to record the call from the time of answer

**2) Forward recorded call to mail**

- If any one attended the call it should start to record from the time of answer.
- Once call ended I need that recorded URL file in Mail

**3) Voice mail trigger**

- If no one answers the call then it should trigger voice mail flow and this also needs to be shared in Email.
- For Voice mail I did Twilio functions and it kept as separate independent flow. Now I want to merge that with call forward flow

**Code Did for call forward:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say> Connecting call A </Say>
        <Dial record ="record-from-answer" timeout="10" hangupOnStar ="true">
            <Number>+1123456</Number>
        </Dial>
  <Say> A is not picking up the call, now connecting call to B </Say>
        <Dial record ="record-from-answer" timeout="10" hangupOnStar ="true">
            <Number>+1234567</Number>
          </Dial>
  <Say> B is not picking up the call, now connecting call to C </Say>
        <Dial record ="record-from-answer" timeout="10" hangupOnStar ="true">
            <Number>+1234587</Number>
          </Dial>
  <Say> No one picking up the call now, please text us at +122233356 or please leave the voice mail after the beep</Say>
</Response>
```

**My Goal:-**

1. If no one attended the call, at that time need to trigger Voicemail function
2. If any on of us attended the call - call should not connect with other users and it should share the recorded call URL to mail

So, please help me like how to do with this.
If possible please share me any sample code/file for practical understandings

Comment: So, you have some code that works for trying different numbers. What did you try for the next part of the question? What isn't working?